# Eliminate double quotes from a json field and deal with characters in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, string, postgresql

Some time ago I needed help with a postgresql database with a jsonb field to convert numerical values surrounded by double quotes into standard numerical values and this solution worked very well:
[Eliminate double quotes from a json field in a selective manner in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64502173/eliminate-double-quotes-from-a-json-field-in-a-selective-manner-in-postgresql)

I had a field named "test_json" which is composed of for example these 2 rows:

```
{"test_name": "Full", "parameter1": "4.219", "parameter2": 4.4137}
{"test_name": "Full", "parameter1": "3.758", "parameter2": 4.159}
```

And the problem was to have these 2 lines after correction:

```
{"test_name": "Full", "parameter1": 4.219, "parameter2": 4.4137}
{"test_name": "Full", "parameter1": 3.758, "parameter2": 4.159}
```

So the proposed solution is really great...

However I have now cases where the database has been fed with a random character instead of a number in this case this conversion does not work.
Example of bad datas:

```
{"test_name": "Full", "parameter1": "4.219", "parameter2": 4.4137}
{"test_name": "Full", "parameter1": "}", "parameter2": 4.159}
```

Or

```
{"test_name": "Full", "parameter1": "u", "parameter2": 4.4137}
{"test_name": "Full", "parameter1": "3.758", "parameter2": 4.159}
```

But it is hardly the same character so I struggle to find and replace them automatically…

Does anyone have an idea for a postgresql function in a json field to test if the value of the field “parameter1” can be converted to numerical and, if not, replace it with a missing value within this field?
Like for example after final correction with old first line to "parameter1": "u"

```
{"test_name": "Full,"parameter2": 4.4137}
{"test_name": "Full", "parameter1": 3.758, "parameter2": 4.159}
```

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=52c2dc6d2d39fe0df9fe28cec330497b)

Deconstruct the JSON element, filter all numeric-like texts and reconstruct the resulting elements:

```
SELECT
    id,
    jsonb_object_agg(key, value::numeric)    -- 3
       ||  jsonb_build_object('test_name', test_json -> 'test_name') as test_json  -- 4
FROM
    t_test,
    jsonb_each_text(test_json) as objects    -- 1
WHERE value ~ '^[0-9\.]+$'                   -- 2
GROUP BY id, test_json
```

1. Deconstruction: All attributes to one row
2. Filter all values that look like numbers
3. Reaggregate the JSON object
4. Add the "test_name" attribute manually, because this attribute was removed by the filter before.

The `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE t_test t
SET test_json = s.test_json
FROM (
    -- <query above>
) s
WHERE t.id = s.id;
```

---

**Edit: 2nd Version using `regexp_replace()`:**

1. Step: Eliminate all non-numeric occurrences text-based using a RegExp:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5f8834aa85e546918cfad2a9fbb799a7)

```
SELECT 
    regexp_replace(
        test_json::text, 
        '"((parameter1|parameter2)": "(?:(?![0-9\.]+).)+?)"', '', 'g'
    )
FROM
    t_test
```

This uses the "negative lookbehind" solution from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/977294/3984221

2. Step: Eliminate the `"` characters with your former approach.

Comment: Thank you!
The problem with deconstruction is that this json field is made up of about a hundred parameters. I've put only a small part here to illustrate... sorry about that

Comment: Added a second approach.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work? I still have: "hysteresis": "}", "max_residuals": 1.876657 for the row that I want to correct for my try

Comment: Could you please add your test cases into the fiddle I provided in the answer. Then I could have closer look at this.

Comment: Thanks, you are right: it should work. I will try again checking any typo in my code on the real database...

Comment: OK so it seems that as soon as I use the real name of the parameter with _ and () in it, it doesn't work anymore. Sorry I am not use to regex function to understand how to correct your code to make it works. I have update the fiddle... thanks again

Comment: Hi, when you updated the fiddle, you must "run" your new version. This generates a new link with the updated data. Please send the new link :)

Comment: Yes sorry it is a RTFM issue! ^^ Here is the new link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bf0e713fe3f9e0326bde14e7d89d811c

Comment: It's the parentheses. You have to escape them in the RegExp: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f49ee3d70ef35324397ebfe0d72a3e11

Comment: Great! Thank you very very much it saves me several hours of database cleaning!

Comment: just one last little question: when I run the regexp_replace function on my real database, dbeaver displays the json field which is well modified: great! But when I go then to see the field with a select from... the field is still at the old value. Isn't regexp_replace supposed to update the json field? Do I have to use another command after that to do this update? Sorry if my question is a low level one I'm a complete newbie in postgresql and database administration... Thank you! The fiddle to illustrate:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=10c753788683981ca5595e4e65253194

Comment: Yes, of course, you need to run an UPDATE command. See my first example and your example how to do this.